# How to showing data from (Meteor) react findOne?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, meteor

I am trying data call from `findOne`. I have put the query in `follwer` variable. when I consoled `console.log('Follower matched', follower)` its showing data but when I want show id with this code `console.log('Follower Id', follower._id)` it's showing error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined` **How can I fix this issue?**
[image: follower]
[image: follower._id]

```
renderTasks() {
    const followersSub = Meteor.subscribe('followers');
    if (followersSub.ready()) { // followers collection has been synced with client
        var follower =  Followers.findOne(
                            {userID : this.props.task._id, followedID: Meteor.userId()},
                            { sort: { createdAt: -1 }}
                        );
        console.log('Follower matched', follower); // should be present now
        console.log('Follower Id', follower._id);    
    }else{
        console.log('Not found');
    }   
}
```

Import API code:

```
import {Events, Followers} from './../../api/events';
```

Publish code in API (events):

```
if(Meteor.isServer) {
Meteor.publish('followers', function() {
      return Followers.find();
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have subsribed to `'Followers'` but the subscription may not be ready yet. The code after `Meteor.subscribe('Followers');` is very likely to find no document yet.

In order to get to know, whether your subscription is ready, you need to check for the `ready()` method in your subscription handle:

```
const followersSub = Meteor.subscribe('Followers');
if (followersSub.ready()) { // followers collection has been synced with client
    var follower =  Followers.findOne(
                        {userID : this.props.task._id, followedID: Meteor.userId()},
                        { sort: { createdAt: -1 }}
                    );
    console.log('Follower matched', follower); // should be present now
    console.log('Follower Id', follower._id);    
}
```

#### Use withTracker to track the subscription state

Now how does your code "wait" until `ready()` is a truthy value? Since a subscription handle is a reactive variable you will use a `Tracker` in order to "track" the subscription's internal state change and act on changes. In the Meteor-React component `withTracker` this is built in by default.

The [Meteor guide on `withTracker`](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#using-withTracker) explains this in detail. If you follow the guide and apply it to your code you should be able to successfully subscribe to your documents.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have used your code the `renderTasks`. But its showing subscription is not ready. How can I fix this?  I have not used `withtracker `.

Comment: API js code: `import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');
export const Followers = new Mongo.Collection('followers');

if(Meteor.isServer) {
   // This method will remove
   Meteor.publish('Followers', function() {
      return Followers.find();
   });
}`

Comment: Please add follow-up code to your question and not in comments. Otherwise it may be hard to get the big picture of what your are doing.